# Neocomplete does not work with vim files

Tags: vim, neocomplete

I just installed Neocomplete and tried it for C files, ruby and python and it works perfectly.
I have problems with vim files as I don't get any omnicompletion at all. I tried `C-x C-o` and got `omnifunc is not set` error

What am I doing wrong? I thought this would work from scratch.

Comment: There is no omnicompletion for vimscript.

Comment: I am talking about Neocomplete plugin in vim. How does it provide autocompletion for vim scripts? And why doesn't it work for my case?

Comment: Again, there is *no* omnicompletion for vimscript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't doing anything wrong. It isn't `neocomplete`'s job to provide  `omnifunc`.

Neocomplete does work well with omni completion: it uses `omnifunc` to provide good candidates for completion, along with other completions provided by vim. However, neocomplete itself does not provide or set `omnifunc` for differnt filetypes. That's why [its configuration example](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim/blob/5adbcdccea200b83b1145378e49600758e227e32/README.md#configuration-examples) has multiple lines with `set omnifunc=..`.

It works with python etc. because the corresponding functions are provided by vim runtime files (e.g. `/usr/local/share/vim/vim74/autoload/pythoncomplete.vim`) or other plugins (like `jedi-vim`),  and the `omnifunc` options are set accordingly (If you want to know where, try `:verbose set omnifunc?`).

Sadly, no function for omni completion for Vim script is provided by default, so you'll need to i) find one and ii) `set omnifunc=(that function)`. After that, neocomplete will be able to use that function to provide omni completion.

---

Edit: as @Martin Macak pointed out, neocomplete-vim's github page does show something like omni-completion. After some digging, it seems these completions come from [Shougo/neco-vim](https://github.com/Shougo/neco-vim), mentioned briefly [in the doc](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim/blob/1977757ec425408d5dc1dfaa9c0ccb67a5c437bb/doc/neocomplete.txt#L997). `i_CTRL-X_CTRL-V` mentioned there is also worth trying.

Comment: Then I don't understand what's on the pictures on neocomplete.vim github page. There's an animated gif showing omnicompletion in vim file, providing function names and more.

Comment: @MartinMacak It seems that neco-vim is used there. Please see my edit.